# how multiple map in automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper

I recently met with an automapper. I have a question, how i can map multiple objects from my repostiory in one DTO.

```
public QuestionProfile()
{
    CreateMap<Question, GrammarQuestionDTO>()
        .ForMember(g => g.Question, q => q.MapFrom(source => source.Text)).ReverseMap();

    CreateMap<List<GrammarQuestionDTO>, TestDTO>()
        .ForMember(t => t.GrammarQuestion, g => g.MapFrom(source => source)).ReverseMap();

    CreateMap<Question, AuditionQuestionDTO>()
        .ForMember(a => a.Question, q => q.MapFrom(source => source.Text))
        .ForMember(a => a.Url, q => q.MapFrom(source => source.AudioFile.Url)).ReverseMap();

    CreateMap<List<AuditionQuestionDTO>, TestDTO>()
        .ForMember(t => t.AuditionQuestion, a => a.MapFrom(source => source)).ReverseMap();
}
```

how can I map all these 4 objects?

```
public async Task<TestDTO> GenerateTest(LevelType level)
{
    var grammarQuestions = await _questionRepository.GetGrammarQuestionAsync(level);
    var auditionQuestions = await _questionRepository.GetAuditionQuestionAsync(level);
    var essayTopic = await _questionRepository.GetEssayTopicAsync(level);
    var speakingTopic = await _questionRepository.GetSpeakingTopicAsync(level);

    var test = _mapper.Map<TestDTO>(grammarQuestions);
    test = _mapper.Map(test, auditionQuestions); //there will be a conversion error

    return _mapper.Map<TestDTO>(grammarQuestions);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to map it without list, just map it one to one and `AutoMapper` will handle the collections:

```
CreateMap<AuditionQuestionDTO, TestDTO>()
    .ForMember(t => t.AuditionQuestion,
               a => a.MapFrom(source => source.<PropertyName>)).ReverseMap();
```

And then on the map you should:

```
test = _mapper.Map<List<AuditionQuestionDTO>>(test, auditionQuestions);
```

Comment: @memento You are welcome. If it helps I would appreciate if you can accept the answer :)

Comment: I tried it, however it did not help in solving the problem.

test = _mapper.Map(test, auditionQuestions); //there will be a conversion error

Comment: please note that I am trying to pass multiple objects to mapper from the repository

Comment: @memento I forgot to mention that you also need to update the map to map `IEnumerable`. I updated my answer.